# Webdriver.io chromedriver download error 404

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, http-status-code-404, wdio

No code change; webdriver.io test site fails to run with error 404 could not download Chromedriver, despite that version being available.

Expecting that running 'npm run wdio' would run my test suite.

Edit: fixed by running 'npm update' beforehand resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

In the ide terminal run 'npm update'

Answer (score 0):

They merged a workaround https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/pull/12305
And released a fix `webdriver v8.32.2` https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/releases/tag/v8.32.2

Update your @wdio packages to `8.32.2`

Answer (score 0):

When run npx wdio run **** command to execute UI automation testing, there is error below:

Error: Download failed: server returned code 404. URL: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.184/mac-x64/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip

After "**npm update**", the error above is solved.